# TFS Release Management to deploy to a separate domain

Tags: powershell, tfs

We have TFS 2017 in premise setup hosted on our internal network. Lets call that tfs.OurInternalDomain.com
TFS application and its build controllers and agents are all hosted on our internal n/w.
Our production servers are hosted on a separate domain (data center) for security reasons.

I am trying to deploy TFS Build artifacts [files and folders] from within our internal n/w onto our production server using TFS Release management definition.
I am able to copy the files using "Copy files from" task onto a folder on our production server (which is on a separate domain) from our internal n/w using a separate ID with $(AdminLogin) and $(Password). This userID is a local admin on the production server. TFS services are running under a separate ID on our domain.

These are the variables for task: "Copy files from"

```
Source=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(BuildDefinitionName)/$(BuildArtifactName)
Machines=$(ServerOneOnSeparateDomain)
Admin Login=$(AdminLogin) 
Password=$(Password)
Destination Folder=$(BuildDropLocation)
```

So far so good.
Next task is to run a powershell script on the target machine and that is where the build agent on our internal n/w is not able to execute the powershell script. I used both -http and https protocol. Below is the error log when http was selected.

```
Executing the powershell script: D:\TFS2017Build\Agent1\tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines\1.0.41\PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1
Deployment started for machine: '<ServerOneOnSeparateDomain>.com:5985'
##[debug]Deployment logs for Deployment operation on <ServerOneOnSeparateDomain>:5985 
##[debug]Permission denied while trying to connect to the target machine <ServerOneOnSeparateDomain> on the port:5985 via power shell remoting. Please check the following link for instructions: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390236System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server <ServerOneOnSeparateDomain> failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.  

Possible causes are:
-The user name or password specified are invalid.
-Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
-Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
-The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
-The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
After checking for the above issues, try the following:
-Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
-Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
```

Below is output when I execute winrm on production server:

```
winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Is there a way to fix this such that we do not disturb the existing TFS architecture of having the TFS Application, Build controller and agents hosted on the InternalDomain and be able to execute a powershell script on a separate domain? If not, is there any other way to fix this?

My end objective is to be able to deploy code to production via TFS that is hosted on our internal n/w.

I may provide more details if required.

Answer (score 0):

According to this part error info:

```
##[debug]Permission denied while trying to connect to the target machine <ServerOneOnSeparateDomain> on the port:5985 via power shell remoting. Please check the following link for instructions: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390236System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server <ServerOneOnSeparateDomain> failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

**Permission denied**  The account used here **must have permission to connect via power shell remoting.**

To establish a PSSession or run a command on a remote computer, the user must have permission to use the session configurations on the remote computer.

**By default, only members of the Administrators group on a computer have permission to use the default session configurations.** Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can connect to the computer remotely.

To allow other users to connect to the local computer, give the user Execute permissions to the default session configurations on the local computer.

The following command opens a property sheet that lets you change the security descriptor of the default Microsoft.PowerShell session configuration on the local computer.

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
```

If that fails try **adding the source to the TrustedHosts** of the remote machine.  You can read how here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx.

*If you want to use https, you need  Configure WinRM to listen on 5986.*

More detail info please refer below similar issue and tutorial:

- [Release Management Error - Permission denied while trying to connect
  to the target machine](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Release-Management-Error-Permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-target-machine)
- [Configuring WinRM over HTTPS to enable PowerShell remoting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/)